# Find command fails with 'No such file or directory' error

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying to run a find command that deletes files older than N days. For some reason it keeps failing with a 'No such file or directory' error. Some files get deleted by a separate process, so I added the flag -ignore_readdir_race in the command but it still fails. I'm running in RedHat Enterprise Server v6.10. This is the command:

```
find "/full/path/to/dir" -ignore_readdir_race -mtime +Ndays -prune -execdir rm -rvf {} +
```

Any thoughts on why it's failing?

Comment: If you want to go along the traditional way: don't use `+` but `\;`, use `-exec` instead of `-execdir` and use the `-depth` flag (and don't use the `-ignore_readdir_race` flag).

Comment: Did it fail without the execution of the command?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf - what's the difference between `+` and `\;` and the point of the `-depth` flag?

Comment: @Amessihel - the command executes and removes some of the directories but eventually it fails once it encounters a file that doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @gabrielh, I mean: if you remove the command execution part `-execdir rm -rvf {} +`, does it fail too ?

Comment: `+` will run the command with all the found arguments, whereas `\;` will run the command with each found file individually. The `-depth` flag will process the directory content before the directory (so that the content of the directory is deleted before the directory itself).

Comment: Don't you need to quote `{}`?

Comment: quoting {} is safe choice, i am (also) usually lazy and don't do it -- echo {} on (zsh) command line shows {} is not expanded to anything -- other thing -- for me find . -depth -name Makefile -execdir make clean {} \; fails when that clean rm -rf subdir. I don't know why -- I just repeat the command line with || if it fails.